# Apparently I was out of line again?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

(This is why I don't run for moderatorship. That and time.)

10k+ (It's deleted) I won't complain if it was re-opened.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765466/what-is-the-purpose-of-an-interface

I didn't think it was a good question (lack of research mostly). I indicated, perhaps rudely, that the OP's C# OOP knowledge was lacking since C# and Java interfaces are identical. I'll point out it was the OOP's language ("very familiar with C# OOP") that made me question how familiar he could be.

I posted a tiny rant on Twitter, without a link to the question. OP found this and tweeted to me a half-dozen times with personal attacks/insults, which I don't react well to, and I'm in his neck of the woods several times a year--this just strikes me as a really bad idea.

Apparently I was also called out here and/or in his profile.

Just doing a sanity check; was I 100% out of line, or just too curt/concise in my response?

Comment: Why I don't use twitter.... to easy to hit send and very difficult to undo it once it is done

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'm fine with being called out, although I thought the personal insults and DDOS threat were a bit much.

Comment: Is your question "should I have Tweeted?"  Apparently not.  This is the Internet.  To find out what the true nature of the Internet is, look at the comment stream below any redneck or Obama video on YouTube.

Comment: In any case, I don't see what relevance *any* Twit.. er, Tweet has to do with anything that goes on at Stack Overflow.  That other people on the Internet choose to turn Twitter into a cesspool is only your fault to the extent that you participate in the stink.

Comment: Just shrug and move on @DaveNewton. Saying things in public will get you public responses. No big deal. Just let it be.

Comment: "I am quite familiar with object oriented programming in c#," "What is the purpose of an interface?"  This is why all those proposals to let users indicate their level of expertise are such a terrible idea.

Comment: *...personal attacks/insults, which I don't react well to, and I'm in his neck of the woods several times a year--this just strikes me as a really bad idea.* - this strikes me as a not-so-veiled threat of violence. Not trying to accuse you of anything, but be mindful of how you word things

Comment: I saw that post and was too late to close so didn't bother responding but I thought the same thing you commented. I've never done **any** C# but I am pretty sure he should know about `interface`s if he's that experienced. Sanity Check == still sane!

Comment: @blahdiblah: As Bill the Lizard [points out in one of his Tweets](https://twitter.com/lizardbill/status/434079846373662721): "Object-Oriented != Interface-Oriented."

Comment: @RobertHarvey But interfaces are just as important in Case as in Java. OP indicated expertise in C#.

Comment: I think you were a bit rude. He asks a question and he has a false perception of his C# know-how. You are an expert. You think his question is ridiculous. Then why you are dealing with his question? Just vote down and move-on.